# need help fixing shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, error-handling, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I recently started using Shiny and I need help with shiny dashboard errors. I am trying to build an app using Shiny Dashboard, But I keep getting errors: "**Error in tagAssert(sidebar, type = "aside", class = "main-sidebar") :
object 'sidebar' not found**"
Can Someone help me fix the error??
Thanks in Advance

```html
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

covid <- read.csv("covid.csv")
covid_deaths <- read.csv("COVID_DEATHS_UK.csv")
noncovid_deaths <- read.csv("NON_COVID_DEATHS_UK.csv")
title <- tags$a(href='https://ourworldindata.org/covid-vaccinations?country=OWID_WRL',
                'COVID 19 Vaccinations')
function(request){
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    hr(),
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("Global COVID data",
                         menuSubItem("COVID vaccinations: Deaths Vs All variable", tabName = "Dashboard"),
                         selectInput("location", "1. Select a country",
                                     choices = covid$location, selectize = TRUE, multiple = FALSE),
                         menuSubItem("Scatterplot", tabName = "Scatterplot", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                         menuSubItem("Regression", tabName = "Regression", icon = icon("cog")),
                         menuSubItem("Multicollinearity", tabName = "Multicollinearity", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                         menuSubItem("Summary", tabName = "Summary", icon = icon("file-o-text")),
                         menuSubItem("DataTable", tabName = "DataTable", icon = icon("table"), selected=TRUE)
                         ),
                menuItem("COVID_Deaths", tabName = "COVID Deaths", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                menuItem("NonCOVID_Deaths", tabName = "Non COVID Deaths", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                )
  )
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Scatterplot",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 6,
                       tabPanel("Scatterplot", plotlyOutput("scatterplot"),
                                verbatimTextOutput("correlation")),
                       tabPanel(helpText("Select variables for scatterplot"),
                                selectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Y-axis:",
                                            choices = c("total_deaths", "new_deaths"), 
                                            selected = "Deaths"),
                                br(),
                                selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "X-axis:",
                                            choices = names(subset(covid,select = -c(total_deaths,new_deaths,
                                                                                     iso_code, continent,date,location), na.rm =TRUE)),
                                            selectize = TRUE,
                                            selected = "Comparator variables")
                                               ))))),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Regression",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 6,
                       tabPanel(verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "regsum"),
                                verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "indprint"),
                                verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "depprint")),
                       tabPanel(helpText("Select input for Independent variables"),
                                selectInput(inputId = "indvar", label = "Independent Variable", multiple = TRUE,
                                            choices = list("total_cases", "total_vaccinations", "people_fully_vaccinated", "total_boosters","stringency_index", 
                                                           "population_density", "aged_65_older","gdp_per_capita","extreme_poverty", "cardiovasc_death_rate", "diabetes_prevalence", "handwashing_facilities", "life_expectancy","human_development_index")),
                                helpText("Select input for dependent variables"),
                                selectInput(inputId = "depvar", label = "Dependent variable", multiple = FALSE,
                                            choices = list("total_deaths","new_deaths","new_cases")))
                       )))),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Multicollinearity",
              fluidRow(
              tabPanel(img(src="Multicollinearity.png"))))),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Summary",
              fluidRow(tabPanel(
                verbatimTextOutput("summary")
              )))),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "DataTable",
              fluidRow(tabPanel(DTOutput("dataset")),
                       tabPanel(helpText("Select the Download Format"),
                                radioButtons("type", "4. Format type:",
                                             choices = c("Excel (csv)", "Text(tsv)", "Doc")),
                                br(),
                                helpText("Click on the download button to download dataset"),
                                downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"))))),
    tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "COVID Deaths",
                     fluidRow(tabPanel(plotlyOutput("hist1")),
                              tabPanel(helpText("Select Variables for a COVID deaths"),
                                       selectInput(inputId = "Yaxis", label = "yaxis:",
                                                   choices = names(subset(covid_deaths, select = -c(Week_number,Week_ending)))))))),
    tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "NonCOVID Deaths",
                     fluidRow(tabPanel(plotlyOutput("hist2")),
                              tabPanel(helpText("Select Variables for a NOn- COVID deaths"),
                                       selectInput(inputId = "ya", label = "Yaxis:",
                                                   choices = names(subset(noncovid_deaths, select = -c(Week_number,Week_ending))))))))
    )
}
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = title),
                    sidebar,body) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$location <- renderPrint({
    locationfilter <- subset(covid, covid$location == input$location)
  })
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(covid)
  })
  datasetinput <- reactive({covid})
  fileExt <- reactive({
    switch(input$type,
           "Excel (csv)" = "csv", "Text (tsv)" = "tsv", "Doc" = "doc")
  })
  output$dataset <- renderDT(
    covid, options = list(
      pageLength = 50,
      initComplete = JS('function(setting, json) { alert("done"); }')
    )
  )
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste("covid", fileExt(),sep = ".")
    },
    content = function(file){
      sep <- switch(input$type,
                    "Excel (csv)" = ",", "Text (tsv)" = "\t", "Doc" = " ")
      write.table(datasetinput(), file, sep = sep, row.names = FALSE)
    }
    
  )
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    #ggplot(subset(covid, covid$location == input$location),aes(y= input$y,x=input$x))+geom_point()
    ggplotly(ggplot(subset(covid, covid$location == input$location),
                    aes(y = .data[[input$y]], x = .data[[input$x]],col = factor(stringency_index)))+
               geom_smooth()+geom_point()+labs(col ="Stringency Index"))
  })
  output$correlation <- renderText({
    x <- covid[covid$location == input$location, input$x]
    y <- covid[covid$location == input$location, input$y]
    xy = data.frame(x,y)
    xy = xy[complete.cases(xy),]
    var(xy)
    cor(xy,method = 'pearson')
    
  })
  output$hist1 <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(covid_deaths, aes(x=Week_number, y= .data[[input$Yaxis]]))+
               geom_point() 
    )
  })
  
  output$hist2 <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(noncovid_deaths, aes(x=Week_number, y= .data[[input$ya]]))+
               geom_point() 
    )
  })
  
  lm1 <- reactive({lm(reformulate(input$indvar, input$depvar), data = subset(covid, covid$location == input$location))}) 
  
  
  
  output$depPrint <- renderPrint({input$depvar})
  output$indPrint <- renderPrint({input$indvar})
  output$regsum <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})
}

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your problem is that the variable `sidebar` only exists in the scope of your anonymous request function

Comment: Got it! thank you!